# Having problems with kubuntu and CUPS

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, printing

I am usimg CUPS 2.2.12 that is preinstalled on my Kubuntu 19.10 on my laptop. I had my Epson Workforce WF-2650 working prefectly with my laptop and CUPS. For some reason it stopped working and now I can not find my printer in the Epson list after I choose my printer. I can not figure out why it stopped working or why the software is not there. I tried to find a way to ask the CUPS people and I could not find a way to contact them. I very very much need my printer working. Please help. All help is very appreciated. Thank you ahead.

After running `ps -fu lp;lpstat -t` in the terminal, here is my output

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
scheduler is running
no system default destination
device for EPSON_WF-2650_Series: usb://EPSON/WF-2650%20Series?serial=554C55593532313441&interface=1
EPSON_WF-2650_Series accepting requests since Mon 30 Mar 2020 03:37:26 PM MDT
printer EPSON_WF-2650_Series is idle.  enabled since Mon 30 Mar 2020 03:37:26 PM MDT
```

Comment: What's in `/var/log/cups/*`? What do `ps -fu lp;lpstat -t` show?

Comment: I was not able to find the /var/log/cups/* file. I input the code above to my terminal. It output this: 'UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
lp         864   708  0 08:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
scheduler is running
no system default destination
device for EPSON_WF-2650_Series: usb://EPSON/WF-2650%20Series?serial=554C55593532313441&interface=1
EPSON_WF-2650_Series accepting requests since Mon 30 Mar 2020 03:37:26 PM MDT
printer EPSON_WF-2650_Series is idle.  enabled since Mon 30 Mar 2020 03:37:26 PM MDT'

Comment: Rather than try to add information in comments, edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1222677/edit ) your post and add it there, properly formatted. As long as you have it in the comments, I won't read it.

Comment: I hope the information added was correct. I am still new and figuring it out as I go.

Comment: It seems incomplete. Your life would be easier if you made it the system default printer with `sudo lpadmin -d EPSON_WF-2650_Series`.

Comment: I added it as a default printer but my problem is not fixed. It spits out 3 labels then prints some crazy triangle thing on a few pages then more blank pages then more triangles and symbols. I have to cancel the print or it will use 50 pieces of paper.